adding audio overlay at a specific point
I am trying to overlay temp.mp3 on top of a.mp3 at timestamp 00:00:10 seconds. Below is the command I am trying to use, but I get the below errors.
temp.mp3 is a short file and I do not want it to loop. Just overlayed once at a specific point on the longer a.mp3 file
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp3 -i temp.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=1[a];[1:0]volume=0.30[b];[a][b]adelay=delay=10s:amix=inputs=2:duration=first" -acodec libmp3lame z1.mp3


Error applying option 'delay' to filter 'adelay': Option not found
Failed to set value '[0:0]volume=1[a];[1:0]volume=0.30[b];[a][b]adelay=delay=10s
:amix=inputs=2:duration=first' for option 'filter_complex': Option not found
Error parsing global options: Option not found


The error you are getting is in the first line: option 'delay' to filter 'adelay': Option not found. The actual name of the option is delays and not delay, so that part of the filter would need to be: adelay=delays=10s.
But apart from that, there are more issues:
The input to adelay needs to be a single stream (and delays the individual channels of the stream), in your case you want to apply adelay only to your [b] stream, so that part would need to be [b]adelay=delay=10s[c].
Then, you need to separate the next filter (amix) by a semicolon ; instead of a colon :, and you need to give streams [a] and [c] (the delayed one) as input.
Your command would then be:
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp3 -i temp.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=1[a];[1:0]volume=0.30[b];[b]adelay=delays=10s[c];[a][c]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" -acodec libmp3lame z1.mp3

See also the documentation about filters here.

Hi, there is no delay in the overlay with this command. The temp.mp3 is overlaying immediately at the beginning of the a.mp3 file. Thanks for helping me with this. I deeply appreciate.

Hi, I changed the duration to milliseconds and it worked, but there is a new problem now. The volume=0.30 level overlaying happened at 20second (20,000 millisecond) point, but a much lower level volume overlaying is also happening right at the beginning of the file. It is audible, can be heard. Also, the entire first section of final file is sort of like in suppressed volume. Then suddenly the volume increases after 20second mark. I don't know how to attach files here to show the originals and the final outputs...

The volume change in the beginning can be explained with amix (during the first 20 seconds there are two inputs, even though the second input is silent during that time, and amix reduces the volume of the first for normalization). After 20+x only the first stream still exists, so amix doesn't normalize any more and volume is identical to the first file again. You can try to play with the amix normalization parameters (especially try normalize=0). The overlay at the beginning of the file I can not reproduce.

I've uploaded the files here: https://munafasutra.com/audios/index.php There are 3 files, a.mp3 (original song), temp.mp3 (dog sound), and z1.mp3 (output file). Also, can you please tell me where to add the normalize option in the command you posted? Many many thanks for helping with this.

Hi, it worked. Turns out my version of ffmpeg was old. I used the newer version on a different server and it worked fine. A million thanks to you for helping me with this! I have marked your answer as accepted answer. Many thanks once again
